# How to sum columns in a dataTable?

Tags: c#, vb.net

How can I get a sum for all the columns in a datatable? Say I had the following table. How can I calculate the "total" row? It should be easy to add total row to a datatable.

```
         Columns    hits     uniques    sigups, etc...
Rows                  
1                      12         1         23
2                       1         0          5
3                       6         2          9


total                  19          3        37
```

**Update**

I ended up with this. It was the only thing I could get to work.

```
 For Each col As DataColumn In TotalsTable.Columns    
    If col.DataType.Name = "DateTime" Then
            count = count + 1
                Continue For
        End If

        Dim colTotal As Double = 0
        Dim value As Double

        For Each row As DataRow In TotalsTable.Rows
            If Double.TryParse(row(col), value) Then
                    colTotal += Double.Parse(row(col))
                    End If
        Next

    totalRow(count) = colTotal
        count = count + 1

  Next
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            int sum = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    sum += (int)dr[dc];
                }
            }
```

Comment: Finally I got the answer from you what i exactly want .Thank You So much

Answer (score 43):

There is also a way to do this without loops using the [DataTable.Compute Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute). The following example comes from that page. You can see that the code used is pretty simple.:

```
private void ComputeBySalesSalesID(DataSet dataSet)
{
    // Presumes a DataTable named "Orders" that has a column named "Total."
    DataTable table;
    table = dataSet.Tables["Orders"];

    // Declare an object variable. 
    object sumObject;
    sumObject = table.Compute("Sum(Total)", "EmpID = 5");
}
```

I must add that if you do not need to filter the results, you can always pass an empty string:

```
sumObject = table.Compute("Sum(Total)", "")
```

Comment: +1 this should be the right answer. It's the framework's exact feature which this question is really asking about.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt that this is what you want but your question is a little bit vague

```
Dim totalCount As Int32 = DataTable1.Columns.Count * DataTable1.Rows.Count
```

If all your columns are numeric-columns you might want this:

You could use [DataTable.Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28VS.80%29.aspx) to `Sum` all values in the column.

```
 Dim totalCount As Double
 For Each col As DataColumn In DataTable1.Columns
     totalCount += Double.Parse(DataTable1.Compute(String.Format("SUM({0})", col.ColumnName), Nothing).ToString)
 Next
```

After you've edited your question and added more informations, this should work:

```
 Dim totalRow = DataTable1.NewRow
 For Each col As DataColumn In DataTable1.Columns
     totalRow(col.ColumnName) = Double.Parse(DataTable1.Compute("SUM(" & col.ColumnName & ")", Nothing).ToString)
 Next
 DataTable1.Rows.Add(totalRow)
```

Comment: Sorry. I want to sum all the columns in a dataTable.

Comment: @chobo: added another approach to sum all rows of all columns.

Comment: So with your technique you can compute the sum for a column, factoring in all the rows?

Comment: @choco: yes, Datatable.Compute with the aggregate function `Sum` will calculate all rows of a column, you could even specify a filter if you want. I iterate through all columns.

Comment: @choco: edited my answer after you provided more informations.

Comment: Hi Tim, sorry for the late reply. I just tried out your solution, but it isn't using the column values, just the header.

Comment: @chobo: The last code-sample will `SUM all` values of a given DataColumn and i iterate all columns. At least it does it by me, if not you should show us the way you've tried it.

Comment: +1 I forgot about `DataTable.Compute`.  Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through the DataColumn and DataRow collections in your DataTable:

```
// Sum rows.
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
    int rowTotal = 0;
    foreach (DataColumn col in row.Table.Columns) {
        Console.WriteLine(row[col]);
        rowTotal += Int32.Parse(row[col].ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine("row total: {0}", rowTotal);
}
// Sum columns.
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns) {
    int colTotal = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row in col.Table.Rows) {
        Console.WriteLine(row[col]);
        colTotal += Int32.Parse(row[col].ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine("column total: {0}", colTotal);
}
```

Beware: The code above does not do any sort of checking before casting an object to an int.

**EDIT: add a DataRow displaying the column sums**

Try this to create a new row to display your column sums:

```
DataRow totalsRow = dt.NewRow();
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns) {
    int colTotal = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row in col.Table.Rows) {
        colTotal += Int32.Parse(row[col].ToString());
    }
    totalsRow[col.ColumnName] = colTotal;
}
dt.Rows.Add(totalsRow);
```

This approach is fine if the data type of any of your DataTable's DataRows are non-numeric or if you want to inspect the value of each cell as you sum. Otherwise I believe @Tim's response using `DataTable.Compute` is a better.

Comment: Is there an easy way to assign the totals to a new row for that datatable?

Comment: @chobo I updated showing how you can add a DataRow showing your column sums.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pity to use .NET and not use collections and lambda to save your time and code lines
This is an example of how this works:
Transform yourDataTable to Enumerable, filter it if you want , according a "FILTER_ROWS_FIELD" column, and if you want, group  your data by  a "A_GROUP_BY_FIELD".
Then get the count, the sum, or whatever you wish.
If you want a count and a sum without grouby don't group the data

```
var groupedData = from b in yourDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r=>r.Field<int>("FILTER_ROWS_FIELD").Equals(9999))
                          group b by b.Field<string>("A_GROUP_BY_FIELD") into g
                          select new
                          {
                              tag = g.Key,
                              count = g.Count(),
                              sum = g.Sum(c => c.Field<double>("rvMoney"))
                          };
```

Comment: I agree. Although I am still reviewing this post, I was shocked to not immediately see a lambda solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (int i=0;i<=dtB.Columns.Count-1;i++)
 {
   array(0, i) = dtB.Compute("SUM([" & dtB.Columns(i).ColumnName & "])", "")                   
 }
```

Comment: It's a good idea to have a small explanation at the start of your solution.