# Sum the total in a column in datatable

Tags: asp.net

I have a question. I need to sum up the total amount in a single column in datatable. How do i proceed with it?

For example

```
Total
2
3
4
5
9
10
```

i need to get a grand total of the whole column.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself first? Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Check these answers out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601752/how-to-sum-columns-in-a-datatable
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892993/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-the-datatable-column-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

The most flexible way is to use [`Enumerable.Sum`](https://www.google.de/search?q=enumerable.sum&aq=f&oq=enumerable.sum&aqs=chrome.0.57j58j0l3.2710&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

```
Int64 sum = table.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => r.Field<int>("total"));
```

Note that you need to add `using System.Linq;`.

You can also use the [`DataTable.Compute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) which syntax is not easy to remember and which is limited:

```
Int64 sum = (Int64) table.Compute("Sum (total)", null);
```

Comment: What is that variable r that u mention in enumerable.Sum?

Comment: @NgYangYang: That is the projected `DataRow` since [`DataTable.AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) returns an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are you using a SQl server you can have the server calculate it and return you the sum..

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Total) FROM MyTable", conn);
int nSum = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```