# C# DataTable How to sort the solution after grouping?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, sql-order-by

I have a table. I grouped that table's rows. The columns are optional.
Columns of the table: day, time, country, city, rain (millimeter).
I would like to copy the solution to a new table.

Code:

```
var q = baseTable.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(row => columnsToGroupBy.Select(c => row[c]), comparer) //eg: day, time, country
.Select(group => new {
AllKeys = group.Key,
AllField = group.Sum(row => double.Parse(row["rain"].ToString()))});
```

Eg. after the grouping it shows how much rain has fallen.

```
q[0]: { AllKeys { "Tuesday, "06:00", "Austria" }, AllField { "1" } }
q[1]: { AllKeys { "Monday", "12:00", "Slovakia" }, AllField { "3" } }
q[2]: { AllKeys { "Tuesday, "06:00", "Slovakia" }, AllField { "1,5" } }
q[3]: { AllKeys { "Monday", "11:00", "Slovakia" }, AllField { "4" } }
```

I would like to sort by the keys in ascending order:

```
q[0] tartalma { AllKeys { "Monday", "11:00", "Slovakia" }, AllField { "4" } }
q[1] tartalma { AllKeys { "Monday", "12:00", "Slovakia" }, AllField { "3" } }
q[2] tartalma { AllKeys { "Tuesday, "06:00", "Austria" }, AllField { "1,5" } }
q[3] tartalma { AllKeys { "Tuesday, "06:00", "Slovakia" }, AllField { "1" } }
```

IF the user would like to change the sorting by the day and time, than it have to sort the columns to day and time.
So this is not work, because I don't know how many keys will be:

```
var q2 = q.OrderBy(x => x.AllKeys.First()))
.ThenBy(x => x.AllKeys.ToList()[1]);
```

Can you help me, how to sort the query?

Comment: You can sort them after you group them when selecting like this `{
AllKeys = group.Key.OrderBy(t=>t),...`

Comment: Is the `GroupBy` working for you? Are you using a special `comparer` that compares `IEnumerable<object>`? Between the `GroupBy` and the `Select` you could put `OrderBy(g => g.Key, comparer)` with an appropriate comparer.

Comment: You will need an extension method to copy the result to a new `DataTable`. What type do you expect to have in the `AllKeys` column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on IEnumerable<T> / IQueryable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet-iqueryablet)

Comment: { AllKeys = group.Key.OrderBy(t=>t),... it's only sort the keys in the query row.

Comment: Yes the comparer is working, I got the idea from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009231/how-to-group-datatable-by-unknown-column-names-and-calculate-sum-of-one-field

Comment: Currently the type of the AllKeys is: System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator<System.Data.DataColumn, object>

Comment: @EugenePodskal I tried with this: var ordered = summed.OrderBy("AllKeys").ToArray(); but it's throw error:

Comment: @EugenePodskal Error: Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in System.Core.dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you can provide a custom `IEqualityComparer` for `GroupBy`, you can provide a custom `IComparer` for `OrderBy`. Basically, `AllKeys` is of type `IEnumerable<object>`, so you need an `IComparer` that takes those and compares each element with the default comparer, but you have to get that using Reflection:

```
public class EnumerableComparer : IComparer<IEnumerable<object>> {
    public int Compare(IEnumerable<object> xs, IEnumerable<object> ys) {
        var xe = xs.GetEnumerator();
        var ye = ys.GetEnumerator();

        var sofar = 0;
        while (sofar == 0 && xe.MoveNext()) {
            if (!ye.MoveNext())
                sofar = 1;
            else {
                var ct = typeof(Comparer<>).MakeGenericType(xe.Current.GetType());
                var c = ct.GetProperty("Default").GetValue(null);
                var fc = ct.GetMethod("Compare");
                sofar = (int)fc.Invoke(c, new[] { xe.Current, ye.Current });
            }
        }
        if (sofar == 0 && ye.MoveNext())
            sofar = -1;

        return sofar;
    }
}
```

With this available, you can do:

```
var q = baseTable.AsEnumerable()
                 .GroupBy(row => columnsToGroupBy.Select(c => row[c]), comparer) //eg: day, time, country
                 .Select(group => new {
                     AllKeys = group.Key,
                     AllField = group.Sum(row => double.Parse(row["rain"].ToString()))
                 })
                 .OrderBy(r => r.AllKeys, new EnumerableComparer());
```

If you want to convert the result to a `DataTable` you'll need to use Reflection but you have the problem of deciding what to do with your `AllKeys` in the result column(s).

Comment: Thank you very much! I create the table from the list of the columns and the operations what the user choose, not from the query. A foreach on this query will fill the DataTable.

Comment: I'd be happy if you could send me sources for learning these techniques.

Comment: @Lother I no longer know all my sources, but I would say a lot of Stack Overflow searching can help you put the pieces together, and a lot of experimentation in LINQPad can help with understanding (the `Dump` method especially) of object structures.

Comment: The only issue with this answer is that it will be done in-memory instead of DB, but depending on the number of keys it may even be for better.

Comment: @EugenePodskal Is there some way to work with `DataTable` that isn't in memory? Note that the original question has `AsEnumerable()` immediately after the `baseTable` and is using field selection syntax for `DataTable`.