# How can I build sums of values from DataTables in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I'm using VB.Net to retrieve data from a database, do some calculations, and then show this data in a datagridview. I already imported the data from the database into a DataTable in my software. So far so good.

Now I want to add up values from columns where another column in the same row has a specific text.

Here's an example. I have data (in the DataTable) in the following form:

```
Date         //   type       //   value
10/09/2020   //   value80    //   92
10/09/2020   //   value71    //   5
10/09/2020   //   value63    //   2
10/07/2020   //   value80    //   85
10/07/2020   //   value71    //   10
10/07/2020   //   value63    //   1
```

I want to build the sum of the 3 `type` values, where "value80", "value71" and "value63" are from the same date. The new variable `value_sum` should be calculated such that for 10/09/2020:

```
value_sum = value80 + value71 + value63 = 92 + 5 + 2 = 99
```

and for 10/7/2020:

```
value_sum = value80 + value71 + value63 = 85+ 10 + 1 = 96
```

How can I calculate the new values in order to save them in another DataTable?

Comment: Have a look at the 2nd answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601752/how-to-sum-columns-in-a-datatable

Comment: One of my edits fixed what I think was a typo in your sample data, changing 10/08/2020 to 10/09/2020. If this was wrong, you can edit the date back in.

Comment: Also, this is probably much easier to do in SQL, where you let the database do this (with a GROUP BY) and return the results back to the vb code.

Comment: One more question: are there any possible `type` values you may encounter in your data? In other words, do we need to be careful to exclude other type values, or can we just sum up everything for the day?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, thanks for you answer! And also thanks for editing my question, you were absolutely right! Right now I have a solution with 2 loops which works. But I have to test it, if it is "safe" or if there are any mistakes. I will build a function in the SQL with a GROUP BY command. Then I will try, if it will optimize my program. To answer your other question. There are other types and sometimes also more than one entry at one day. So it is not possible, to just build the sum for each day.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer, thanks for your answer. I had a look at the answers, but it didn't really helped for my problem. But anyways, I found a solution by just building 2 loops. But thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Linq query we Group By the date field and select the date and the sum. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/queries/group-by-clause There is a .CopyToDataTable method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable?view=netcore-3.1) but I don't know if or how it works with anonymous types. It is easy enough to just loop through the query result and  add the rows to the new DataTable.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    'Create original DataTable with your sample data
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("ValueDate", GetType(Date))
    dt.Columns.Add("Type", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Value", GetType(Integer))
    With dt.Rows
        .Add(#10/09/2020#, "value80", 92)
        .Add(#10/08/2020#, "value71", 5)
        .Add(#10/09/2020#, "value85", 2)
        .Add(#10/07/2020#, "value80", 85)
        .Add(#10/07/2020#, "value71", 10)
        .Add(#10/07/2020#, "value63", 1)
    End With
    'Select the date groups and sum by group
    Dim TotalsByDate = From row In dt.AsEnumerable
                       Group By DateValue = row.Field(Of Date)("ValueDate")
                           Into Dates = Group, Sum(row.Field(Of Integer)("Value"))
                       Select DateValue, Sum
    'Prepare a new DataTable
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable
    dt2.Columns.Add("DateGroup", GetType(Date))
    dt2.Columns.Add("DateSum", GetType(Integer))
    'Fill the new DataTable
    For Each item In TotalsByDate
        dt2.Rows.Add(item.DateValue, item.Sum)
    Next
    'Display results
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt2
End Sub
```